# Qunit beforeEach, afterEach - async

Tags: testing, asynchronous, qunit

Since start(), stop() will be removed in Qunit 2.0, what is the alternative for async setups and teardowns via the beforeEach, afterEach methods? For instance, if I want the beforeEach to wait for a promise to be finished?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

QUnit basically wants people to stop using the [global methods](http://qunitjs.com/upgrade-guide-2.x/#removed-globals) (not just `start()` and `stop()`, but also `test()`, `expect()`, etc). So, as of version 1.16.0, you should always use either the global namespace (`QUnit`) or the `assert` API argument passed into the `test()` functions. This includes the new [async control](http://api.qunitjs.com/category/async-control/):

```
QUnit.test( "testing async action", function( assert ) {  // <-- note the `assert` argument here
    var done = assert.async();  // tell QUnit we're doing async actions and
                                // hold onto the function it returns for later

    setTimeout(function() {  // do some async stuff
        assert.ok( true, "This happened 100 ms later!" );

        done();  // using the function returned from `assert.async()` we 
                 // tell QUnit we're don with async actions
    }, 100);
});
```

If you are familiar with the old `start()` and `stop()` way of doing things, you should see that this is extremely similar, but more compartmentalized and extensible.

<del>Because the `async()` method call is on the `assert` argument into the test, it cannot be used in the `beforeEach()` function. If you have an example of how you were doing that before, please post it and we can try to figure out how to git it into the new way.</del>

**UPDATE**

My mistake previously, the `assert` object is being passed into the `beforeEach` and `afterEach` callbacks on modules, so you should be able to do the same logic that you would do for a test:

```
QUnit.module('set of tests', {
    beforeEach: function(assert) {
        var done = assert.async();
        doSomethingAsync(function() {
            done(); // tell QUnit you're good to go.
        });
    }
});
```

(tested in QUnit 1.17.1)

Comment: I have the same problem. Here's my use case when doing integration testing for an Ember app: https://gist.github.com/tygriffin/0d8cae37c47b243588b9

Comment: @niftygrifty I would recommend doing that call once before any tests or module run and delaying the start of QUnit using `QUnit.config.autostart = false;` and then once the `$.get()` finishes save the return data and call `QUnit.start();` to get things going.

Comment: That's a good idea for the isolated use case I linked to, but ideally I'd like to have a teardown endpoint as well as many different setup endpoints. I'd also like to do set up and teardown at least between every module, if not between every test. As far as I can tell `QUnit.start()` can only be called once to kick off the entire suite of tests. Is that right?

Comment: So actually... it looks like now the `assert` object is being passed into the beforeEach/afterEach methods! I'll update my answer, but looks like you can use the same syntax as you do in tests for module setup and teardown.

Comment: Thank you so much for double checking that! I wish I owned this question so I could mark it accepted.

Comment: ;) Thanks... some day @mattan-bitner will see how awesome it is and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that nobody has answered the beforeEach/afterEach part: a test suite is supposed to run as soon as the page loads. When that is not immediately possible, then resort to configuring QUnit:

```
QUnit.config.autostart = false;
```

and continue with setting up your test suite (initializing tests, feeding them to QUnit, asynchronously waiting for some components to load, be it AJAX or anything else), your site, and finally, when it's ready, just run:

```
QUnit.start();
```

[QUnit's docsite](https://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.config/) has it covered.

Answer (score 0):

Ember Qunit, has once exists `beforeEach`/`setup`, `afterEach`/`teardown` co-exist for a little while.

See PR: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-qunit/pull/125